# SimpleDateFormat - day, month, time are incorrect

Tags: java, simpledateformat, unix-timestamp

This code converts a vendor proprietary timestamp in hex (radix16) format to a Unix time.  I know from the Java docs that the `SimpleDateFormat` is zero-based month (`Jan=0`), however, when converting from a Unix timestamp to a human readable format using the format string, neither the month, day nor time is correct (see the results in the comments near the end).

Expected:

```
Yr 2010 Mo 1 Da 4 Time 13513407 (03:45:13:407).
```

Results:

```
HR:20100205_032123239.
```

The month is `02` instead of `01` (as expected), but the day is `05` instead of `04`.  The hour (`03`) is correct, but the `mins`, `secs`, and `millis` are not.

I've included the pass "text" value used for testing in the comments.

```
public static long parseUnsignedHex(String text) {
    // text = "07DA010400CE32BF"
    long bsUnixTs = 0;
    if (text.length() == 16) {
        String bsYr = text.substring(1, 4);
        String bsMo = text.substring(5,6);
        String bsDa = text.substring(7,8);
        String bsTime = text.substring(9,16);
        try {
            long bsYrL = Long.decode("0x" + bsYr);
            long bsMoL = Long.decode("0x" + bsMo);
            long bsDaL = Long.decode("0x" + bsDa);
            long bsTimeL = Long.decode("0x" + bsTime);
            Calendar bsCal = Calendar.getInstance();
            bsCal.set((int)bsYrL, (int)bsMoL, (int)bsDaL);
            bsCal.setTimeInMillis(bsCal.getTimeInMillis() + bsTimeL);
            bsUnixTs = bsCal.getTimeInMillis();
            System.out.printf("Yr %d Mo %d Da %d Time %d%n", bsYrL, bsMoL, bsDaL, bsTimeL);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Throwable e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmssSSS");
    // convert unix into yyyyMMdd_HHmmssSSS Human Readable (HR) format
    String[][] arTimeString = new String[1][2];
    for(int i=0; i<arTimeString.length; i++){
        arTimeString[i][0] = Long.toString(bsUnixTs);
        arTimeString[i][1] = sdf.format(bsUnixTs);
        try {
                System.out.format("Unix:" + arTimeString[i][0] + " HR:" + arTimeString[i][1]);
                System.out.println();
                // result:
                // SimpleDateFormat - month is zero-based
                //                    the day of month may be incremented because the time is 03:45:13:407
                // Yr 2010 Mo 1 Da 4 Time 13513407
                // Unix:1265358083239 HR:20100205_032123239
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    return bsUnixTs;
}
```

Comment: *"SimpleDateFormat is zero-based month (Jan=0)"* - I think you'll find that relates to `Calendar`...

Comment: `Calendar#set` does NOT reset the values for hours, minutes or milliseconds, when you add `bsTimeL` you are adding on additional time from when the `Calendar` was first created, not setting it's time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, change...

```
Calendar bsCal = Calendar.getInstance();
bsCal.set((int)bsYrL, (int)bsMoL, (int)bsDaL);
bsCal.setTimeInMillis(bsCal.getTimeInMillis() + bsTimeL);
```

To

```
Calendar bsCal = Calendar.getInstance();
bsCal.set((int) bsYrL, (int) bsMoL - 1, (int) bsDaL, 0, 0);
bsCal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
bsCal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
```

This will result in the output

```
Yr 2010 Mo 1 Da 4 Time 13513407
Unix:1262537113407 HR:20100104_034513407
```

`Calendar` uses `0` based months, not `SimpleDateFormat`, also, when using `Calendar#set` it will only affect the fields you supply, leaving the `hour`, `minute` and `second` and `millisconds` unchanged from the time the `Calendar` was created (which is a snapshot of that time/date value)

So what your original code was doing was capturing a snapshot of the current date AND time, resetting the year, month and day values, the adding an additional time value to the CURRENT time...

Comment: Yes, after sleeping on it, and before i saw your answer, i also tried `         `bsCal.set((int)bsYrL, (int)bsMoL, (int)bsDaL, 0,0,0);` , however, my millis is still incorrect so I'll use your technique.  Thx @MadProgrammer